# String.format: 2 => 02

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

```
       String formatted = String.format("%d:%d", 2, 5);
```

I will output `2:5`

But I want: `02:05`, and I don't want extra zero for numbers > 9. In this case it should show like: `10:35`

How can I modify `String.format` method to work in this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use this format:

```
String formatted = String.format("%02d:%02d", 2, 5);
```

Comment: btw: this will make a string of length 2, I do not know what will happen if you use longer numbers (for instance `134`). You should test that :)